# If $\Im\left(\frac{z-i}{2i}\right)=0$, then the locus of z is

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\frac{z-i}{2i}$$

$$=\frac{zi-i^2}{2i^2}$$

$$=\frac{zi+1}{-2}$$

$$\frac{(x+iy)i+1}{-2}$$

Since imaginary part is 0
$$\frac{x}{-2}=0$$
So the locus is $x=0$ ie. Y axis.

But the given answer is the line $x=y$.

Can I get an explanation on how that happened?

Comment: I get the same answer as you via a different method (reframing it with conjugates and solving algebraically). Also, we would have $\Im\left(\cfrac{\color{red}{(i)}-i}{2i}\right)=0$, which is not on the line $\Re{(z)}=\Re{(y)}$ but $\Im\left(\cfrac{\color{red}{(1+i)}-i}{2i}\right)=-0.5$, which is. So maybe the answer you're given is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. Namely, setting $x=1$ and $y=1$, we get:
$$\Im\left(\cfrac{1+i-i}{2i}\right)=\Im\left(\cfrac{1}{2i}\right)=\Im\left(-\cfrac{i}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\ne0$$
The answer given is wrong.